# how to get the value of checksum in php header

Tags: php

I have a header in php which contains a link like

```
<?php
header("Location: "."https://abc.com/ppp/purchase.do?version=3.0&".
    "merchant_id=<23255>&merchant_site_id<21312>&total_amount=<69.99>&".
    "currency=<USD>&item_name_1=<incidentsupporttier1>&item_amount_1=<1>&".
    "time_stamp=<2010-06-14.14:34:33>&**checksum=<calculated_checksum>**");
?>
```

when i run this page the value of checksum is calculated and the link is opened

now how checksum is calculated?
calculated_checksum=md5(abc);

md5 is an algorithm which calculates the value of checksum based on certain values inside the bracket.

now i want to know how can i pass the value of checksum in the header url

Comment: please edit your question. so we can read your code better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean:

Use [string concatenation `.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) :

```
$calculated_checksum=md5('abc');
header('Location: https://...&checksum=' . $calculated_checksum);
```

Variables have to start with `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$cs = md5("abc"); //Puts 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72 (the hash of abc) into  the variable named $cd

header("Location: "."https://abc.com/ppp/purchase.do?version=3.0&".
    "merchant_id=<23255>&merchant_site_id<21312>&total_amount=<69.99>&".
    "currency=<USD>&item_name_1=<incidentsupporttier1>&item_amount_1=<1>&".
    "time_stamp=<2010-06-14.14:34:33>&**checksum=" . $cs . "**"); //Redirect the page to the new page with the checksum concatenated onto the end

?>
```

Is that what you were looking for?